# Given an array of objects is it possible to generalize a function to give the string-literal-union of the values of a given key?

Tags: typescript

Given this reference code:

```
const stuff = [
  { name: "Rock", children: [{ name: "Pebbles", children: undefined }] },
  { name: "Tree" },
  { name: "Sun" },
] as const

// Evaluates to `type Names = "Rock" | "Pebbles" | "Tree" | "Sun"`
type Names = typeof stuff[number]["name"] | typeof stuff[0]["children"][0]["name"]
```

Is it possible to generalize the Names type so that I can have it give me the string literal union of all the `name` property values no matter where it is in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aleksxor's answer has the right idea, but it can be greatly simplified:

```
type Names<K extends string> = {name: K, children?: readonly Names<K>[]}
type NamesOf<T extends Names<string>> = T extends Names<infer K> ? K : never

// "Rock" | "Pebbles" | "Tree" | "Sun"
type Test = NamesOf<typeof stuff[number]>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgZwDwGkoQB7AgOwBNkplgAnAS3wHMA+KAXigG99EIAuKdAGigDGAC0oAbQuQIB+bpLiEA9vlEhYHNOjoBtALoBfALAAoUJDVJkAeQBmqACpZcBYuZSoyVWnQbMHOPEQk8Bao1NYQ5DwMUjxQ3PgQAG4RxsYCSmSkwACu1tZMUFrGUKxQ7EjcAEQASgoCANaV-MJiEgTcWixlHFUAChAARgOiKE2CIuKS+NzZRBDW1BCEUHo6K7zFpeVcUJV2khCV65td21UAyrNHehtGa3Ak6fhkqUYA9G+7tQ1HAD67-SGI2Qf12+wghyg-0ql3wlWMpmgdhQwAKwRQNlQiIU+TIuWsWnw2QQAwiOjoxiAA)

Answer (score 2):

That's possible with the help of [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) types and a bit of recursion:

```ts
type Names<T> = T extends readonly unknown[] ?
    T[number] extends infer O
        ? O extends object
            ? {
                [K in keyof O]: 'name' extends K 
                    ? O[K] 
                    : Names<O[K]>
            }[keyof O]
            : never
        : never
    : never
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq8KQN)

---

First we check whether the `T` type is an array type:

```ts
 T extends readonly unknown[] ?
```

Next we kind of introduce type variable `O`:

```ts
T[number] extends infer O
```

that's totally cosmetic step as I don't want to repeat `T[number]` everywhere where now `O` appears in the type. Due to [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) nature of conditional types `O` now on each iteration has the type of each
*iterated* array element.

Checking whether `O` is in fact an object:

```ts
? O extends object
```

And finally the main part. [Mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) type immediatelly reduced into a union by `[keyof O]` lookup:

```
{ 
    [K in keyof O]: 'name' extends K ? O['name'] : Names<O[K]>
}[keyof O]
```

This one essentially *iterates* over all the keys of `O` object and if the key value is `name` get's the type of `O[K]` otherwise tries to extract the `name` keys type from `O[K]`.

It may help to grasp what is happening inside if we remove `[keyof O]` lookup:

```ts
type Names<T> = T extends readonly unknown[] ?
    T[number] extends infer O
        ? O extends object
            ? {
                [K in keyof O]: 'name' extends K ? O[K] : Names<O[K]>
            }
            : never
        : never
    : never

const stuff = [
  { name: "Rock", children: [{ name: "Pebbles", children: undefined }] },
  { name: "Tree" },
  { name: "Sun" },
] as const

/*
type N = {
    readonly name: "Rock";
    readonly children: {
        readonly name: "Pebbles";
        readonly children: never;
    };
} | {
    readonly name: "Tree";
} | {
    readonly name: "Sun";
}
*/
type N = Names<typeof stuff>
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBz3kN)

And when we make `[keyof O]` lookup for each of the mapped objects we get:

```ts
type N = {
    readonly name: "Rock";
    readonly children: {
        readonly name: "Pebbles";
        readonly children: never;
    }['name' | 'children'];
}['name' | 'children'] | {
    readonly name: "Tree";
}['name'] | {
    readonly name: "Sun";
}['name']
//
type N = "Rock" | "Pebbles" | "Tree" | "Sun" // result type
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbkPBW)